# How to run Asp.net Webforms Website with MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I have an website (with website template .net4). I have done website admin panel. I want to run website admin panel and mvc4 web application for end user site. It is possible?

Comment: ................What?

Comment: yes you can see this tutorial : http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run webforms and mvc at the same time on the same website (if that is your question). There are lots of articles on the subject on the web... for example:
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: how did you know he updated OP's question @RahulNikate?

Comment: To who ever cares... I did not upvote anything. And on a side note I wasn't sarcastic either... and I think others should try not to be either. Over and out - This is my last comment on this post.

Comment: @RahulNikate thanks for being sarcastic..I have been member longer than you and know what I am doing. The whole idea is to help people and not care about downvote/upvote